# using arcpy.da.walk to inventory data and export metadata to csv

Tags: python, csv, arcgis, arcpy

I'm a novice when it comes to arcpy and am trying to develop a script that will use arcpy.da.walk to inventory our GIS data. As it goes through the folders/gdbs of data that we have, I want it to export a few items to a csv for each feature class (for now I'd be happy with feature class path, filename, spatial reference name and metadata purpose). I've gotten the script to work up until the metadata purpose part. Once I add the lines:

```
arcpy.ExportMetadata_conversion(feature_class, translatorpath, xmlfile)  
tree = ElementTree()  
tree.parse(xmlfile)   
spot = tree.find("idinfo/descript/purpose")
```

my script does not return anything. Without those lines, I recieve a csv file with feature class path, filename, and spatial reference name, but if I include the lines my csv file is empty. No errors, just empty. My script (included below) is based off of: https://arcpy.wordpress.com/tag/os-walk/ and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34729/creating-table-containing-all-filenames-and-possibly-metadata-in-file-geodatab/34797#3479/.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDITED: Some feature classes may not have a spatial reference defined, and many feature classes may not have any metadata associated. I still want these in the csv, but those fields can either be blank or say something along the lines of "No spatial reference defined" and "No metadata purpose defined".

```
import os
import arcpy
import csv
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
from arcpy import env

def inventory_data(workspace, datatypes):
    for path, path_names, data_names in arcpy.da.Walk(
            workspace, datatype=datatypes):
        for data_name in data_names:
            yield os.path.join(path, data_name)

AGSHOME = arcpy.GetInstallInfo("Desktop")["InstallDir"]  
translatorpath = AGSHOME + "Metadata\\Translator\\ARCGIS2FGDC.xml"
outfile = "C:\\GIS\\Records\\Data  Management\\Inventories\\GIS_Data_Inventory_daWalk_function_outputtocsv_descitems_try_sr_meta.csv"
 xmlfile = "C:\\GIS\\Records\\Data Management\\Inventories\\TempInventoryError\\daWalk_function_outputtocsv_descitems_try_sr_meta.xml"

with open (outfile, 'wb') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for feature_class in inventory_data(r"C:\GIS\Data\Natural_Environment\Species_and_Habitats\Habitat_Models", "FeatureClass"):
         try:
            desc = arcpy.Describe(feature_class)
            sr = desc.spatialReference
            arcpy.ExportMetadata_conversion(feature_class, translatorpath, xmlfile)  
            tree = ElementTree()  
            tree.parse(xmlfile)   
            spot = tree.find("idinfo/descript/purpose")
            csvwriter.writerow([desc.path.encode('utf-8'), desc.file.encode('utf-8'), desc.dataType.encode('utf-8'), sr.name.encode('utf-8'), spot.text.encode('utf-8')])
         except:
             pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding "my script does not return anything":

You have put your commands in a `try ... catch` block, but your `catch` does not do anything. If you printed the Exception messages you probably would have seen these arcpy errors:

> ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
>   ERROR 000725: Output File: Dataset C:\tmp\test.xml already exists.
>   WARNING 000725: Output File: Dataset C:\tmp\test.xml already exists.

To resolve this issue you have to delete the `xmlfile` and the start (or end) of each iteration in your `for`, if I understand correctly it's only being used as a temporary file anyways.

```
# your other imports here
import traceback

with open (outfile, 'wb') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for feature_class in inventory_data(r"C:\some directory", "FeatureClass"):
        try:
            if os.path.isfile(xmlfile):
                os.remove(xmlfile)

            # your other code here
        except Exception:
            print "Failed: ", feature_class
            print traceback.format_exc()
```

---

Regarding writing missing data to CSV:

It depends on the kind of operation you are doing and what data it yields. For your `spot` variable you want to check if the output from [`tree.find`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.find) is `None`.

From the documentation:

> ... Returns an element instance or None.

Use a second variable, e.g. `spot_text`, to store your text value and write it to the CSV instead:

```
spot = tree.find("idinfo/descript/purpose")
if spot == None:
    spot_text = "No metadata purpose defined"
else:
    spot_text = spot.text.encode('utf-8')
```

Or shortened:

```
spot = tree.find("idinfo/descript/purpose")
spot_text = spot.text.encode('utf-8') if spot != None else "No metadata purpose defined"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I figured this out last week through trial and error, and help on Esri's Geonet forum. Full answer can be seen here: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/186717-using-arcpydawalk-to-inventory-data-and-export-metadata-to-csv